# Index structure of open-ended tuples

Tags: typescript

I understood tuples as an array of the union of all elements, augmented by a fixed length, and named properties. Else said, `[number, string]` would be equivalent to `{ [K: number]: number | string, '0': number, '1': string, length: 2 }` plus all array methods typed for that tuple.

However, for open-ended tuples, i can't find any alternative way to express them:

```
type Open = [number, ...boolean[]];
type NotFirst = Open[1]; // boolean
```

I can find, that `[number, ...boolean[]] extends { [K: number]: number | boolean, '0': number } ? 'yes' : 'no'` evaluates to `'yes'`, but to achieve the above, something like `{ [K: number]: boolean } & { '0': number }` would be necessary (can't even write it in one go anymore, need intersection), which however doesn't seem to be used.

Any changes to the type immediately widen whatever it is, to an index structure for the union of all elements (and also removes the neat out-of-bounds check for indexing):

```
type UnnamedElement = ([number, ...boolean[]] & { extra: boolean })[1]; // number | boolean
type NoBoundsCheck = ([number] & { extra: boolean })[1];                // no error
```

Are tuples just special, and there is no way (yet?) to produce something similar, or am i misunderstanding something?

Comment: It seems to be related to the [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40945).